# MediaError Access to screen denied while trying to implement Screenshare

Tags: sdk, access-denied, screensharing, agora.io

I am using the Web SDK for `Agora.io` and trying to implement video chat feature and have screen sharing enabled. I am having this error generated:

> MediaError "Access to screen denied."

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Which platform are you using to test the screen sharing?

Agora's screen sharing does not work in Safari, and needs a plugin to run in Chrome. Only FireFox supports screen-sharing out of the box.

The plugin process is available within the Agora documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_web?platform=Web